# Why is my panel not updating the textarea in java

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

I have a JPanel that contains 3 panels. The layout of the panel is a BorderLayout and the 3 panels are divided by using BorderLayout.NORTH, .CENTER, and .SOUTH. The panel that is set to .SOUTH is called "bottom". In bottom there is a textArea that should display info according to what the user selected from the comboBox in the panel above it. For some reason however, my text area is not updating the information. The idea is that when the user selects "Mountain Bike" for example, the text area will display the info about the mountain bike. Then, if the user selects "Road Bike" immediately after that, it will display info about the road bike. It's not doing this for some reason, and I know for sure that it is a matter with updating it because all my class instances are correct and when I tried selecting different starting indexes for the combo box, they all displayed the correct info in the text area. Here is my constructior:

```
    public MainGUI(){
       System.out.print("Loading...");
       frame.setVisible(true);
       frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       frame.add(main);
       int frameSize = frame.getWidth();
       instructionField.setColumns(frameSize);
       instructionField.setEnabled(false);
       instructionField.setDisabledTextColor(Color.RED);
       instructionField.setText("Welcome to the Bike App! Please choose from the following bikes!");
       Color backColor = frame.getBackground();
       instructionField.setBackground(backColor);
       main.add(instructionField, BorderLayout.NORTH);
       main.add(middle, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       main.add(bottom, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
       GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
       gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
       gbc.gridx=0;
       gbc.gridy=0;
       middle.add(bikeComboBox, gbc);
       submit = new JButton("Load Selected Bike");
       gbc.gridx=1;
       gbc.gridy=0;
       middle.add(submit, gbc);
       bikeComboBox.addActionListener(this);
       submit.addActionListener(this);
       //bottom is a JPanel
       //HERE IS WHERE THE TEXT AREA CODE IS
       informationTextArea = new JTextArea();
       JScrollPane sp = new JScrollPane(informationTextArea);
       informationTextArea.setEditable(false);
       bottom.add(informationTextArea, BorderLayout.CENTER);
       //bikeComboBox.setSelectedIndex(1);
       selectedBikeIndex = bikeComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
       selectedBikeName = bikeTypes[selectedBikeIndex];
       String returnedInfo = loadSelectedBikeInfo(selectedBikeName);
       informationTextArea.setText(returnedInfo);
       informationTextArea.updateUI();
       bottom.updateUI();
       informationTextArea.setBackground(backColor);
       frame.setSize(400,400);
    }
```

Here is the loadSelectedBikeInfo(String selectedBikeName) method:

```
    public String loadSelectedBikeInfo(String selectedBikeName){
      String s = selectedBikeName;
      String selectedInfo = "";
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.mounBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = mountainBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.roadBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = roadBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.raciBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = racingBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.cruisBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = cruiserBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      return selectedInfo; 
    }
```

Here is the actionPerformed method for the button, not the combo box (I don't know how to write one for a combo box):

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
      if(e.getSource()==submit){
         selectedBikeIndex = bikeComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
         selectedBikeName = bikeTypes[selectedBikeIndex];
         loadSelectedBikeObject(selectedBikeName);
      }
    }
```

EDIT: I wrote an actionPerformed method in a different class and added that listener to my combo box. Why is it still not updating?

```
    public class ComboBoxUpdateListener implements ActionListener{
      private MainGUI maingui;

      ComboBoxUpdateListener(MainGUI _mainGUI){
         this.maingui = _mainGUI;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
         JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)(ae.getSource());
         String bikeTypePassed = maingui.bikeTypes[cb.getSelectedIndex()];
         System.out.println("This is from the LISTENERCLASS: "+bikeTypePassed);
         maingui.loadSelectedBikeInfo(bikeTypePassed);
         maingui.informationTextArea.updateUI();
         maingui.bottom.updateUI();
      }
    }
```

Comment: And where do you update the text area content from the selected bike name?

Comment: in the loadSelectedBikeInfo method, disregard the comments. I copy pasted the if statement four times and forgot to modify the comments.

Comment: @JBNizet I think I update it in my constructor where it says "bottom.updateUI()". I also updated my text area too in the same place.

Comment: There is no `informationTextArea.setText(selectedInfo);` in this method. So obviously, the text area is not updated.

Comment: Where is your ActionListener code since this is where you'd get the selected item and use it to update your JTextComponent?

Comment: @JBNizet no OP's using that method to get the string that OP uses to in `String returnedInfo = loadSelectedBikeInfo(selectedBikeName); informationTextArea.setText(returnedInfo);`

Comment: Yes there is, where it says informationTextArea.setText(returnedString) in the constructor. Does it have to be in the method?

Comment: Georgio: just because it's called once in the constructor does not mean that the method will be called mathemagically whenever the user selects the item. You have to write an event listener and update your text area in that listener.

Comment: You're calling that method in the constructor. So it's called only once, when the GUI is constructed. If you want to update the text area each time the selection changes, you must do it... each time the selection changes: in your actionPerformed() method.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Sorry, I'm still getting accustomed to Java. So if I write an event listener in a different class and add that ActionListener to the combo box in the constructor should it update? And what about my loadSelectedBikeInfo method? Should that be in the listener or in the class it already is. I was trying to avoid writing a listener but I guess if it has to be done it has to be done.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just wanted to show that where it is called

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana: you already have an event listener added to the JComboBox, the ActionListener which looks to be the GUI class itself. As JB Nizet writes -- what is in your actionPerformed method?

Comment: @Abu: jb nizet knows where it is called, and knows that this call is completely useless in this position.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels ok i got it

Comment: @Hovercraft That's the thing: in terms of the actionListener on the combo box there is no associated actionPerformed method because I didn't know how to write an actionListener for a combo box. Instead, I added a button and wrote an associated actionPerformed method for the button that basically prints out the String of the selected index of the combo box.

Comment: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
       if(e.getSource()==submit){
           selectedBikeIndex = bikeComboBox.getSelectedIndex();
           selectedBikeName = bikeTypes[selectedBikeIndex];
           loadSelectedBikeObject(selectedBikeName);
       }
    }

Comment: weird: it was indented when I pasted it into the comment box.

Comment: @GeorgioMahugana: don't try to post code in comments as formatting is lost. Post it as an edit to the end of your original question.

Comment: Have you gone through the [combo box tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html)?

Comment: I edited it my question, and yes I took a look at the tutorial but I still can't really find what I'm looking for.

Comment: I should also mention that loadSelectedBikeObject is a different method that passes a string and for now just prints it out. The reason I have this button is that I don't want the user to select an option from the combobox and every time the user selects something a GUI pops up. I still need to know how to write an actionListener for a combo box.

Comment: You write it exactly the same way as you would write it for a button. Instead of button.addActionListener(...), you just call comboBox.addActionListener(...). Re-read the combo-box tutorial.

Comment: I wrote a listener class and added it to my post. For some reason that gui is still not updating. Could you please take a look?

Comment: Nevermind i figured it out. Just forgot to set text.

Comment: You still don't update the text of the textarea from the listener's actionPerformed() method. Stop calling updateUI(). It doesn't do what you think it does. Read its API doc. Calling it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 3):

> when I tried selecting different starting indexes for the combo box,
>   they all displayed the correct info in the text area.

Well take a close look at what you have done to the working code:

```
String returnedInfo = loadSelectedBikeInfo(selectedBikeName);
informationTextArea.setText(returnedInfo);
```

As per your edit:

> EDIT: I wrote an actionPerformed method in a different class and added
>   that listener to my combo box. Why is it still not updating?
>
> ```
>   @Override
>   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
>      JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)(ae.getSource());
>      String bikeTypePassed = maingui.bikeTypes[cb.getSelectedIndex()];
>      System.out.println("This is from the LISTENERCLASS: "+bikeTypePassed);
>      maingui.loadSelectedBikeInfo(bikeTypePassed);
>      maingui.informationTextArea.updateUI();
>      maingui.bottom.updateUI();
>   }
> ```

`loadSelectedBikeInfo(bikeTypePassed)` returns a `String`:

```
public String loadSelectedBikeInfo(String selectedBikeName){
      String s = selectedBikeName;
      String selectedInfo = "";
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.mounBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = mountainBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.roadBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = roadBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.raciBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = racingBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      if(s.equalsIgnoreCase(this.cruisBikeType)){//load mountain bike info
          selectedInfo = cruiserBike.getBikeInfo();
      }
      return selectedInfo; 
    }
```

So you should get that `String` and call `setText(String text)` on the `JTextArea`:

```
  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
     JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)(ae.getSource());
     String bikeTypePassed = maingui.bikeTypes[cb.getSelectedIndex()];
     System.out.println("This is from the LISTENERCLASS: "+bikeTypePassed);
     String info=maingui.loadSelectedBikeInfo(bikeTypePassed);
     maingui.informationTextArea.setText(info);
  }
```

- Please also have a read on [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html).
- Also as said by others [`updateUI`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html#updateUI%28%29) does not help you:

> Resets the UI property with a value from the current look and feel.

if anything maybe `repaint()` should be called but I see no reason for this.

- Dont use `setSize` implement a correct [`LayoutManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and call `pack()` after adding contents but before setting `JFrame` visible